# MVC Redirecting Action using Json

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Purpose: The code written is suppose to save all the contents using Json and re direct to action.

Problem: 
The current redirect using Json does not allow the redirection as suppose.
return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status }  };

The code is below for reference: Looking for suggestions:

View Code

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/SA/Save',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json",

    success: function (d) {
        //check is successfully save to database
        if (d.status == true) {
            //will send status from server side
            alert('Successfully done.');

            window.location.href = d.Url;
            //clear form
            t = [];
            d = [];
            r = [];
            $('#SN').val('');
            $('#SA').val('');
            $('#t').empty();
            $('#d').empty();
            $('#r').empty();
        }
        else {
            alert('Failed');
        }
        $('#submit').val('Save');
    },     
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Save(SAVM O,)
{
    bool status = false;

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SA s = new SA
        {
        }

        _db.SA.Add(O)
        _db.SaveChanges();
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        status = false
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status }  };
}
```

Here want to redirect like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("F", "SA");
```

but using JsonResult

Solution

View

```
$.ajax({ 
url: '/SA/Save',
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(data),
dataType: "JSON",
contentType: "application/json",

success: function (d) {

window.location.href = d.Url;

})
} });
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult Save(SAVM O,)

{

var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    SA s = new SA
    {
    }

    _db.SA.Add(O)
    _db.SaveChanges();

 return Json(new { Url = "F/SA" });
```

}

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax.

Comment: Yes understandable, but incase if using JsonResult then any suggestions or work arounds for redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, you decide which one you prefer based on your requirements.

1. Do not use AJAX. AJAX requests are meant for data required for the current page. You should use a synchronous request for the redirection.
2. Return the URL to which the client should redirect on the `success` event:

   ```
   return Json(new { url = "/F/SA" });
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   success: function (d)
   {
       window.location.url = d.url;
   }
   ```
3. Return the already rendered View and load it to the current page:

   ```
   return View("some view...");
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   success: function (d)
   {
       $("#someElement").html(d);
   }
   ```